# Modx - How do you deploy from a subfolder to root?

Tags: php, apache, modx, modx-revolution

salutations and good tidings as I humbly bring forth my request :D

I just started using Modx and used it to redsign my website.

My OLD website is still intact and RUNNING.

For example purposes let us call the old website - www.thisismywebsitefoo.com/

The new MODX based website is up and running.

Again for example purposes we shall call it - www.thisismywebsitefoo.com/modx

Okay so now I want to CLOBBER my old website and have the new Modx website take over ... only thing is I don't know HOW to do this *correctly*.

I would like to think that I can just do some webserver setting or something that makes the website point to the modx staged directory while still showing as www.thisismywebsitefoo.com

How do you deploy from a subfolder to root? What is the correct way to do this?

=======

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my OWN question ... woohoo!

I found a good article on the bluehost website. For those sites that use CPanel there is a way - http://www.bluehost.com/cgi/help/347

Answer (score 0):

Backup the site.

Change paths in the configs and the use the site.

Forcing a redirect via Apache .htaccess and other means simply slows down the site and increases the overall load on the server.

References:
http://forums.modx.com/thread/70111/moving-modx-site-from-sub-folder-to-root-folder#dis-post-392762

https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/moving-your-site-to-a-new-server